# In hash table, why not update h(x)(=h0(x) itself but use h1(x), h2(x) ..?

Tags: hashtable, collision, hash-function, probing

In hashtable, let’s say that
H0(x) = x mod m
And if we say that to avoid collision, we use linear probing 
Hi(x) = (x + i) mod m

But whatever the hash function is, whether we do linear probing or quadratic probing, While searching for a key, it has to go through all the collisions right?

So the idea is like this :
What about updating the hash function h(x) itself as
If element a, after passing all the collisions, was placed in
(H0(a) + La) mod m
Then what about updating the hash function itself as
H(x) = h0(x) + La*f(x-a)
while f(x-a) is 1 only if x=a ?
Then, when later searching for a, we dont have to go through all the collisions but just find the element rightaway..?
What is the problem with this idea?

Comment: `while f(x-a) is 1 only if x=a `. You'll need another Map to store this information (as well as `La`). Or you can literally create such function; then its computation time will be linear.

Comment: @dyukha ooh then it will be no use using hash table since its computation time wont be O(1)..